# eBay API call RelistFixedPriceItem doesn't accept a ListingType of "FixedPriceItem"

Tags: ebay-api

I am trying to use the eBay API call [RelistFixedPriceItem](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/relistfixedpriceitem.html) relist an item as fixed price which has been listed as an auction before.

The "interesting part" of my XML request looks like this:

```
<RelistFixedPriceItemRequest>
    <Item>
        <ListingType>
            FixedPriceItem
        </ListingType>
    </Item>
</RelistFixedPriceItemRequest>
```

But still, eBay responds that I can't use the ListingType I used ("FixedPriceItem") but should use "FixedPriceItem" (the same) instead:

```
<RelistFixedPriceItemResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">
    <Timestamp>2013-06-21T14:14:52.951Z</Timestamp>
    <Ack>Failure</Ack>
    <Errors>
        <ShortMessage>Unsupported ListingType.</ShortMessage>
        <LongMessage>Valid Listing type for fixedprice apis are FixedPriceItem and StoresFixedPrice.</LongMessage>
        <ErrorCode>21916286</ErrorCode>
        <SeverityCode>Error</SeverityCode>
        <ErrorClassification>RequestError</ErrorClassification>
    </Errors>
    <Version>827</Version>
    <Build>E827_UNI_API5_16161102_R1</Build>
</RelistFixedPriceItemResponse>
```

Has anyone run into this issue - or found a workaround?

Nothing in their [API documentation](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/relistfixedpriceitem.html) states that this shouldn't be possible. It certainly is on ebay.com where you can change the listing type when you relist an item.

Answer (score 0):

Well, If you look at their [API documentation's Sample XML](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/relistfixedpriceitem.html#samplebdxBasic), you would notice that they do not use

```
  <ListingType>
      FixedPriceItem
  </ListingType>
```

That suggests to me that, when you use the **RelistFixedPriceItem** call you do not have to specify the **Listing Type** to be *FixedPriceItem*

I do agree that it is a confusing error.